# Trying to check from a table with data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new in SQL and somehow landed a job that requires me to do SQL (don't lie in your resume kids). Anyway, I'm trying to do a SELECT statement, where I want to select a columnA in tableA where the words in ColumnA exists in another tableB, below are an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
TableA, ColumnA : {Apple, Ball, Chair, Doll, Egg, Fan, Gun, Hat, Ink, Jug}
TableB, ColumnB : {Chair, Ball, Egg, Ink}
```

So I tried to come up with the statement of what I wanted as below

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA = (SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB)

OR

SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%' + (SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB) + '%'
```

Of course it doesn't work because it will return more than 1 value. I'm still very new in this and can't figure out how to use some functions like CURSOR. Help is very appreciated. Thanks.

(EDIT) : So from the answers, using IN and JOIN both can solve what I need. Thank you very much for that. However, I also want to know for the case that I need to use LIKE, let's say the columnA and columnB has

```
ColumnA : {'This apple is red', 'This ball is round', 'This chair is metal'}
ColumnB : {'red', 'round'}
```

So I want to display data from columnA that has the keywords that exists in columnB. I'm thinking of the only way is to combine wildcards and select from columnB. Help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the data actually saved to the database in the format above or is that some type of shorthand?

Comment: As well as changing the = to IN, try to avoid the double wildcard:
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/the-two-ways-to-fix-non-sargable-queries/

Comment: @RossBush just a shorthand, but the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA IN (SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB)
```

or (better to do)

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnB
```

Comment: This helps, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**sql server 2016** and higher version you can use `string_split` function for this scenario.

```
select * from tableA t1
cross apply string_split(t1.ColumnA, ',') t2
where t2.Value in 
(select t2.value from tableB t1
cross apply string_split(t1.ColumnB, ',') t2)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=51acdfc04e8b60d9d5a8cba6f7fbdc42).

for **sql server 2014**, we need to use recursion queries with `string` functions.

```
with cte as
(
    select
        left(ColumnA, charindex(',', ColumnA + ',') - 1) as col1 ,
        stuff(ColumnA, 1, charindex(',', ColumnA + ','), '') as col2
    from tableA
    union all
    select
        left(col2, charindex(',', col2 + ',') - 1),
        stuff(col2, 1, charindex(',', col2 + ','), '')
    from cte
    where
        col2 !=  ''
), cte2 as 
(
    select
        left(ColumnB, charindex(',', ColumnB + ',') - 1) as col1 ,
        stuff(ColumnB, 1, charindex(',', ColumnB + ','), '') as col2
    from tableB
    union all
    select
        left(col2, charindex(',', col2 + ',') - 1),
        stuff(col2, 1, charindex(',', col2 + ','), '')
    from cte2
    where
        col2 !=  ''

)
select * from cte where rtrim(ltrim(col1)) in (select rtrim(ltrim(col1)) from cte2)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=922c49f4ecd859fcfb7d89c831ce962e).

Comment: unfortunately im using sql 2014 :(

Comment: @FareastAbdullah, we need to use recursive queries. see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select TableA.ColumnA 
from TableA JOIN TableB
on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnB
```